# Problema al tratar de obtener valor en jComboBox con getSelectedIndex()

Tags: java

tengo un jComboBox creado por medio del diseñador de netbeans, ya le asigne el contenido que esta dentro (Disponible, Transito, Despachado), pero a la hora de querer sacar el valor del combobox por medio de getSelectedIndex() solo selecciona una opcion, ahi esta el cosigo:

```
    String RESTADO = "";

    public String ESTADO(){


    int estado = paquete.ComboBoxEstado.getSelectedIndex();

    if (estado == 0){

        RESTADO = "Disponible";

    }else if (estado == 1){

        RESTADO = "Transito";

    }else{

        RESTADO = "Despachado";

    }
         return RESTADO;  
}
```

Comment: `getSelectedIndex();`solo devuelve la primera opción seleccionada.

Answer (score 0):

Ya que estas usando una función, lo ideal sería pedir como parámetro un combo, un ejemplo sería:

```
public String obtener(JComboBox elCombo){
        return (String) elCombo.getSelectedItem();
    }
```

o si el método lo usas dentro de la clase:

```
public String obtener() {
        return (String) nombreDelCombo.getSelectedItem();
    }
```

Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Cuando creas un JComboBox seleccionas un índice por defecto. Ese será el que te devuelve. Para detectar cambios en el JComboBox deberías hacerlo con un ActionListener()